# How to print pointer variable from a structure in C?

Tags: c

I need to print out a pointer variable within a structure.  I assume i must de-reference but am not sure how without getting a segmentation fault.

```
struct HealthProfile{ //structure with pointers to all needed variables.
    char *name;
    char *last;
    char *gender;
    struct date *dob;
    float *height;
    float *weight;
};

void readData(){
    float height;
    printf("What is your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", &H.name); //scan
    //H.name = name;
    printf("What is your last name? \n");
    scanf("%s", &H.last);
    //H.last = last;
    printf("What is your Height name? \n");
    scanf("%f", &H.height);


    printf("Height: %f\n", *(H.height));
    //printf("First Name: %s\n", H->name);
    //printf("Last Name: %s\n", H->last);
}
```

I want it to print out the scanned in height which is a float.

Comment: Where do you declare `H`?

Comment: `scanf("%s", &H.name);` is a type error. `%s` takes a `char *`, not a `char **`.

Comment: Why does your structure contain pointers? What is `H` and how did you initialize it?

Comment: @melpomene H is an instance of the structure, i declared it above this code globally but only included this section, I am using pointers because that is what the assignment asks me to put into the structure

Comment: How was `H` initialized?

Comment: `height` and `weight` should probably be `float` rather than `float*`. The other fields make sense as pointers.

Comment: You have a structure of pointers. But *where do those pointers really point?*

Comment: Also welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve]. In particular, you are missing the declaration for the variable named `H` which causes irrelevant compiler errors when I try to compile your code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of declaring `float height;`, you need to declare `struct HealthProfile H;`. Better yet, declare `struct HealthProfile profile;` and replace `H` everywhere with `profile`.

Next, fix your `scanf()` statements. For example

```
scanf("%s", &H.name);
```

should be

```
scanf("%s", profile.name);
```

Similarly change

```
scanf("%f", &H.height);
```

to

```
scanf("%f", profile.height);
```

Now your syntax for `printf()` will be correct.

**However, you will still have problems because non of your pointers have been allocated memory.** Declaring the `name` and `last` fields as pointers makes sense. However, I think you should declare `float height;` and `float weight;` instead of using pointers for these values. If you do so, then your original `scanf()` statements with the `&` operator will be correct.

Comment: Calling `scanf` without checking its return value is a bug. Using `%s` (without a limit) is also a bug.